# Can't install Laravel Socialite via composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-socialite

I'm trying to require Laravel Socialite following the composer command in the DOCs but it's showing me the below error. Anyone knows what to do?

I'm using Laravel 9 and I don't think it's related to anything in my project so no need for code snippets.

hitting `composer require laravel/socialite` doesn't seem to work.

[image: err]

Comment: https://support.reytheme.com/kb/how-to-fix-a-curl-error-28-connection-timed-out/#:~:text=Make%20sure%20your%20server%20is,be%20a%20dns%20related%20issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a network issue. I restarted my internet and it worked.